# TYPO3: Add attribute to RTE table

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have previously used this TypoScript snippet in my setup to add a class to a table.

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    externalBlocks {
        table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class {
            default = table table-hover
            always = 1
            list >
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly in TYPO3 6.x, but does not do anything in version 4.5. Is there any other method to do this?

While at it, I'd also like to add `data-*` to the table headers.

Comment: Did you make sure this is applied correctly? Have a look in the TS object browser on the very page you want this to work... oh, and don't forget to check any TS conditions you might need!

Comment: "worked perfectly in Typo3 6.x, but does not do anything in version 4.5" - are you sure you need to get this running on 4.5!? Or did you confuse version numbers?